# Unable to continue with the webpage as red box appears on input type search,this occurs only in IE and not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

The zipcode should allow 5+4 numeric, in chrome it lets me to enter 5+4 characters but in IE it gives a weird red box. 
If i remove last 4 numbers, it allows me to continue in IE.

I tried using different properties for sectionZipValue class but didnt work

```
<td class="tdLabelWidth"><form:label class="sectionLabel"
                        path="addressAndHousingInformation.preZipCode">State & Zip Code</form:label></td>
                    <td class="tdInputWidth"><form:select
                        path="addressAndHousingInformation.preState" id="formBwrPrevState">
                        <form:option value="0">Select</form:option>
                        <form:option value="AL">AL</form:option>
                        <form:option value="AK">AK</form:option>
                        <form:option value="AZ">AZ</form:option>
                    </form:select>


<form:input class="sectionZipValue" id="formBorrowerPrevStateZipcode"
                        path="addressAndHousingInformation.preZipCode" type="search"
                        maxlength="9" /> <form:label id="errorbwrPrevState"
                        class="sectionError" path=""></form:label> <form:label
id="errorborrowerPrevStateZipcode" class="sectionError" path=""></form:label></td>

[.sectionZipValue{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 90px;
    min-width: 70px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}][1]

java code:
address.setZipCode(fromObj.getAddressAndHousingInformation().getZipCode());
            if(!"".equals(fromObj.getAddressAndHousingInformation().getZipCode()))
            {
                String fullZipcode = fromObj.getAddressAndHousingInformation().getZipCode();
                String zipcode = "";
                String ext = "";
                if(fullZipcode.contains("-"))
                {
                    zipcode = fullZipcode.substring(0, fullZipcode.indexOf("-"));
                    ext = fullZipcode.substring(fullZipcode.indexOf("-")+1, fullZipcode.length());
                }
                else
                {
                    zipcode = fullZipcode;
                    ext = "0000";
                }
                address.setZipCode(zipcode);
                address.setZipCodeExt(ext);
            }
```

Expected results: When i click on submit, it should allow me to submit all the details in the page including the full zip code(5+4 numeric) in IE.

Actual: When I click on submit, a red box appears on the field, this issue occurs in IE

Comment: What is doing the validation?

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: When I click continue on the page, the validation happens.                                <div id="prQualOfferButtons" align="center""><br clear="all" />
 <form:button id="searchCancel" class="mybutton" name="cancel"
  value="Cancel">Cancel</form:button> <form:button id="searchContinue"
  class="mybutton" name="continue" value="Continue">Continue</form:button>
 </div>